# (android) how to set background of TextView with black-transparent color

Tags: android

I want to set my background of LinearLayout and textview with black-transparent color so that the picture behind them can be seen well.

I tried with the code below, but it doesn't work

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No Comments"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_comments"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No Comments"
android:textSize="22dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="#CCFFFFFF"/>
```

**You can change the transparency by changing first two character("CC") with below codes**

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
 5% — 0D
 0% — 00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

Style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
            <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        </style>
```

Color.xml

```
<color name="transparent">#CCFFFFFF</color>
```

If you want change transparent Layout;

Layout.xml

```
     <activity android:name="com.ex.ex"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
</activity>
```

And Text View

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_comments"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No Comments"
android:textSize="22dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="#CCFFFFFF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Or you can use alpha**

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_feed_myPlant_comments"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No Comments"
android:textSize="22dp"
android:alpha="0.5"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```